# Baked Normal error, looks disconnected on certain faces

Tags: normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

[image]

As the image shows, there's a disconnection on the pointed edge loop.
The model on the left is the high poly model and it doesn't looks like the bake result.
It seems like the normal map is not applied on the lighter part at first glance, but then I drew a dark blue on the normal and it does show on the model.

[image]

The bake setting used is showed below, I've tried checking cage option but it doesn't seem to help.
I'm currently using Blender 3.0, any idea how I may fix this problem?

[This is my file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zyse5yi-URynVxVKE7wYMM2x5guD32wJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think to do anything other than guess, we'd need a file to look at.

Comment: @Nathan  You've got a point, I'll add the file link in the post

Answer (score 2):

There are actually a lot of problems here.  Like, all the problems you could possibly have.  Sorry :(

1. Let's start with the UV map.  To bake, you need each face mapped to a unique part of the UV map.  Here, we with linked selection, we can see that you have multiple parts of your low poly mapped to the same part of the UV space:

[image]

2. You have doubled faces that create non-manifold geometry on some places of your low poly.  Use select non-manifold operation and disable "boundaries" in operator panel to see problem areas that you have to fix.
3. Your low poly is getting its base normals modified by both sharp edges and autosmooth.  While there is justification for sharp edges on a normal mapped low poly sword, that requires better knowledge than you have right now (use of a cage.)  For now, you want only smooth shading on your low poly, as any sharp edges will lead to discontinuous sampling of your high poly.  Autosmooth is right out, never use it on a low poly.
4. Your low poly mesh also has intersecting faces.  At any points where two faces intersect each other, you're going to have discontinuous normals on your map.  This one is probably the most related to the particular issue you have here.
5. Your high poly also has some non-manifold geometry.  It also has self-intersecting geometry.  At any of these locations, you will get discontinuities in the normals of your low poly, because your normals are discontinuous across the visible surface of your high poly.
6. Your bake settings are poor here.  You have a ray extrusion of 0.1.  Let's look at what that means:

[image]

That's a displacement of 0.1 along normals, which is exactly what ray extrusion does.  We can see a lot of self-intersection afterwards, which is going to give us messy high-to-low bakes.  An extrusion of 0.06 would be appropriate here, but we could make a small edit to the low poly and use an extrusion of only 0.02 or so, which would be better.

Plus, you have max ray distance set to 0.1 as well.  So if we use an extrusion of 0.1, and distance of 0.1, we'll only ever see bits of the high poly that are **outside** of our low poly.  Generally, you don't want to use max ray distance ever, just leave it at 0 (which actually means infinity.)

Comment: I feel really lucky to made all these errors and having someone willing to give such a detailed an clear instruction, thanks alot Nathan!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here make sure your object has all normal  straight, turn on this feature shown to check it, if it has red area/faces means they are flipped and cause that problem which us showed, to fix it , press Shift+N to recalculate, also check the same for the high poly. Secondly:- maybe lower down your ray distance from 0.1 to something like 0.01 or something like that if it doesn't help plz upload the file so I can take a better look, It can be a seam issue or smoothing groups , if u could share the file I can take a better look at ur problem. But I think recalculate normal can fix it.

Comment: Hi! I've checked normal and bake setting and sadly they don't seems to work. <https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zyse5yi-URynVxVKE7wYMM2x5guD32wJ/view?usp=sharing> this is my blend file, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think Nathan answered the issues and problems perfectly, here you need yo get these free addons, these will help you with finding Non-manifold object/faces/verts etc :- https://app.gumroad.com/d/8c2ebc15962e8c42873d1ab909429e96

second for checking overlapping UVs
https://github.com/SavMartin/TexTools-Blender

Third here learn how to make mirror UVs don't overlap
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqxUIGp7-TI

Here for UV shifting using mirror modifier
[image]
[image]

This is kinda advance stuff which you will learn by experience and by learning from courses, The explaination above Nathan is more better than mine, have safe blending, and learn about the things he mentioned, your low poly must always fully overlap ur high poly rather than interesecting like your model is doing. anyways here is the fix for now
[enter link description here](https://we.tl/t-n7PrPloMAX)
https://we.tl/t-n7PrPloMAX

Comment: These are all so helpful, thank you NamanDeep! I couldn't seem to get the first addon(the one for Non-manifold geometry) through the link, could you give me the name of the addon? So that maybe I can try to get it through other way.

Comment: Here sorry I didn't realize that link was from my account, here is the official link  https://vfxgrace.gumroad.com/l/apny?recommended_by=library